# Display all associated children with wsapi.Store

Tags: rally, code-rally, wsapi

I've been searching for a way to display all the defects for a project and it's 
children in Rally, however I can't seem to find the right way to go about this.

In the constructor it seems there is no parent property, however I've seen this property used in previous versions using wsapiStore. What is the correct way of doing this now?

Here's a look at my code:

config.json:

```
{
    "name": "BasicRallyGrid",
    "className": "CustomApp",
    "server": "https://rally1.rallydev.com",
    "sdk": "2.1",
    "javascript": [
        "App.js"
    ],
    "css": [
        "app.css"
    ]
}
```

---

Call to Store:

```
this.myStore= Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model: 'Defect',
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: myFilters,
            /*filters: Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
                property: 'Parent',
                operator: '=',
                value: "SomeParent"
            }),
            listeners: {
                load: function (myStore) {
                    if (!this.myStore) {
                        this._createGrid(myStore);
                    }
                },
                scope: this
            },
            fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Severity', 'Iteration', 'Project']
        });
    }
},
```

---

My Grid code:

```
_createGrid: function (myStore) {
    this.myGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
        store: myStore,
        columnCfgs: [
            'FormattedID', 'Name', 'Severity', 'Iteration', 'Project'
        ]
    });
    this.add(this.myGrid);
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, as this is my first question here, if I broke some etiquette please let me know so I can avoid it in future posts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use project scoping... Check out this guide: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/data_stores-section-scoping

By default your store will inherit your global scoping, so I would have expected it to just work, but depending on what you're doing you may have to explicitly specify your project scope + up/down.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this worked! I was originally hard coding in the filters which isn't good practice. Now I can get rid of a ton of code. Thanks again!